# I want to assign a laravel id into my formData in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, form-data

I am trying to add a 'common_id' to my laravel project but instead of an html form I am using formData so the value field doesn't work, any ideas how I can insert this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="common_id" value="{{$common->id}}">
```

into this:

```
  $("#done").click(function(){
      let upload_image = mainCanvas.toDataURL('image/png', 98)
      // console.log("Image URL:", upload_image)

      let one_file = urlToFile(upload_image)
      uploadOne(one_file)
    });

    let urlToFile = (url) => {
      let arr = url.split(",")
      // console.log(arr)
      let mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1]
      let data = arr[1]

      let dataStr = atob(data)
      let n = dataStr.length
      let dataArr = new Uint8Array(n)

      while(n--){
        dataArr[n] = dataStr.charCodeAt(n)
      }

      let file = new File([dataArr], 'First.png', {type: mime})

      return file
    }

    let uploadOne = (file) => {
      const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/store"
      
      const payload = new FormData()
      // payload.append('file', file)
      payload.append('file', file)

      fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: payload,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, 
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      })
    }
```

without the html input tag and just using form data

I have tried using another append tag as such

```
const commonId = "$common->id"
      
      const payload = new FormData()
      // payload.append('file', file)
      payload.append('file', file)
      payload.append('hidden', common_id, commonId);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: how about putting the id in the `data-` attribute of button ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use common id like this:

```
const commonId = "{{ $common->id }}"
```

Comment: thank you, I tried that already but it doesn't work.